# Can "né" or "née" be used to refer to a religious's secular name?

Tags: politeness, religion, forms-of-address

Is "né" (masculine) or "née" (feminine) ever used to refer to the secular name of a [religious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_(Western_Christianity)) (i.e., monk or nun)?

For example:

- Sr. Mary Dominic (*née* Jill Smith)

or

- Br. Raphael Thomas (*né* Charles Gates)

It would seem so, because *né* or *née* simply means "born".

Comment: *Religious* is shown as a plural noun in M-W and AHD, but that would not support "a religious".

Comment: It's also a singular noun in OED. "2. A person bound by religious vows or devoted to a religious life, esp. in the Roman Catholic Church." It's a technical term, but we do allow technical terms.

Comment: The more common usage of née is to denote the maiden name of a married woman. As stated in the answer below by @Laurel it is also legitimate, though uncommon, to use it in reference to the prior secular name of someone who takes a new religious name. Up-voted +1.

Comment: It is used, as a Google search shows. Whether it's ever considered impolite, insulting or offensive, and whether there is a better alternative, is another, harder question you should consider.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Actually, [the *full* OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161956?redirectedFrom=religious#eid) defines the noun use as *B 1. With **plural** agreement. **People** bound by monastic vows or devoted to a religious life, esp. in the Roman Catholic Church.* OP's  usage struck me as a "mis-translation" from French, but I stand to be corrected on that point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And B 2.?

Comment: @xngtng: Ooops! My mistake! I hadn't scrolled down to even realise there ***was*** a B.2! It still sounds "French" to me, though.

Comment: Can you please say a little more about why you are asking this question.  There are many different reasons for changing the name(s) by which a person is known, of which monastic tradition is one.  There are also pseudonyms and noms de plume for a variety of purposes both legal and criminal.  In British law you can call yourself whatever you like.  As some female novelists, like George Eliott, have done, or rock stars.  If you want to take out a mortgage or obtain a passport, however, there are legal procedures required.  'né(e) is mainly a biographical usage.  So why do you need to know?

Comment: In my opinion, when writing in English it is best to avoid foreign terms when equivalent English is available, because the English is more likely to be understood. “Born” is extremely common and will be understood by nearly everyone, “né” is obscure.

Comment: @MarkDominus Strunk & White's _Elements of Style_ does suggest what you say.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sure, but it's uncommon; "born" is the typical word. I found some examples online:

- > Through his papal letters, his teachings and pilgrimages, John Paul II - ne Karol Josef Wojtyla, the first non-Italian pope in 455 years - reminds us that the biggest story of all is not man's hunger for the legalistic meaning of "is," but the age-old search for the meaning of life. — [He's no Bill Clinton](https://www.ctinsider.com/news/article/He-s-no-Bill-Clinton-3063901.php)
- > Pope John Paul II (ne Karol Jozef Wojtyla) and Pope John XXIII (ne Angelo Giuseppe Roncalli) are scheduled to be declared saints by the Roman Catholic Church on Sunday, April 27, 2014 in Rome. — [Pope John Paul II Canonization Marred by Link to Sex Abuse Scandal](https://www.bishop-accountability.org/news2014/03_04/2014_04_22_Baral_PopeJohn.htm)
- > Another character of great importance is POPE URBAN IV, nee [sic] James Pantaleon. — [How a Miracle of the Eucharist Brought about the Feast of Corpus Christi](https://www.catholic365.com/article/12599/how-a-miracle-of-the-eucharist-brought-about-the-feast-of-corpus-christi.html)

Comment: That last one should be "né".

Comment: @Geremia It should, but the error is the author’s, not Laurel’s. The quotation is accurate to the source. And the use of “née” for a woman’s name prior to marriage is so much more common in English (and the notion of gendered participles so foreign, literally!) that many readers will never have encountered the masculine, and will use “née” indiscriminately, I expect.

Comment: @TimPederick Yes, I realize that.

Comment: I rarely encounter "née", let alone "né"; Diacritic marks being foreign to most English speakers, they tend to write "nee" in all cases.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to add a [sic] after the "nee"

Comment: @MartinKealey My experience is very different to yours. I'm much more used to seeing _née_ properly accented; _nee_ looks decidedly wrong to me.